# Sum of binomial coefficients with increasing $n$

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any formula for calculating $$\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n+1}{2} + \binom{n+2}{3} + ... + \binom{n+m}{m+1}$$

I have tried iterative method but is there any constant time method exist.

Comment: With only a tiny bit of manpulation, you can apply [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rising_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients) formula.

Comment: With some different manipulation, you should be able to use [this formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173760/computing-a-sum-of-binomial-coefficients)

Answer (score 10):

Let's add in an initial value of $1 = \binom{n}{0}$.  The fundamental relationship

$$\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k}\tag{1}$$

makes the sum telescope:

$$\eqalign{
&\color{Blue}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1}}  &+\binom{n+1}{2} &+ \binom{n+2}{3}  + \cdots &+ \binom{n+m}{m+1} \\
& =\color{Blue}{\binom{n+1}{1}} & +\color{Blue}{\binom{n+1}{2}} &+ \binom{n+2}{3} + \cdots &+ \binom{n+m}{m+1} \\
& &=\color{Blue}{\binom{n+2}{2}} & +\color{Blue}{\binom{n+2}{3}}+ \cdots &+ \binom{n+m}{m+1} \\
& & & = \cdots \\
& & & = \color{Blue}{\binom{n+m}{m}} &+\color{Blue}{ \binom{n+m}{m+1}} \\
& & & &= \color{Blue}{\binom{n+m+1}{m+1}}.
}$$

Subtracting the $1$ originally added in gives the answer, $\binom{n+m+1}{m+1}-1$.

---

Antoni Parellada kindly points out (in a comment below) that this fundamental relationship $(1)$ is now often called "Pascal's Rule."  This appendix shows how intimately connected that eponym is with the present question.

Here, from Pascal's Complete Works (republished by Hachette, Paris, in 1858 as *Oeuvres Completes*), is his original diagram of the "Arithmetical Triangle" as it appeared in the *Traité du Triangle Arithmetique* (1654).

[image: Figure]

Pascal has labeled many of the cells with Greek and latin letters for reference.  After giving its rule of construction--the fundamental relationship above--he draws 18 "consequences."  The second consequence is the present result.  Like many of his time, Pascal's proof proceeds by demonstrating the relationship for a specific case in a way that obviously generalizes:

[image: Figure 2]

(From a translation at http://cerebro.xu.edu/math/Sources/Pascal/Sources/arith_triangle.pdf.  I discovered the original some years ago on the Cambridge University Library Web site but apparently it has been put behind a private wall since then.)  It's a nice graphical way to display the telescoping.

Comment: thnx very much..

Comment: The first identity is [Pascal's rule](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_Rule/Combinatorial_Proof#Proof)

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{n+1}{2} = \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} = \binom{n}{1} + \frac{n-1}{2} \binom{n}{1}$

$\binom{n+2}{3} = \binom{n+1}{2} + \binom{n+1}{3} = \binom{n+1}{2} + \frac{n-1}{2} \binom{n+1}{2}$

$\binom{n+3}{4} = \binom{n+2}{3} + \binom{n+2}{4} = \binom{n+2}{3} + \frac{n-1}{3} \binom{n+2}{3}$

...

...

$\binom{n+m}{m} = \binom{n+m-1}{m-1} + \binom{n+m-2}{m} = \binom{n+m-1}{m-1} + \frac{n-1}{m-1}\binom{n+m-1}{m-1} $

Start with $n$ and store each value starting from $\binom{n+1}{2}$ to calculate $\binom{n+2}{3}$ [O(1) operation] and so on.